# Django - Manage.py ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite' on windows

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get Django to work. I installed Django used

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

This created this structure

```
mysite 
-- manage.py
-- mysite
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py 
    - etc etc...
```

now I'm when I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get this error

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\MySoftware\python361\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\MySoftware\python361\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\MySoftware\python361\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\MySoftware\python361\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\MySoftware\python361\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Python cannot find 'mysite'
I've tried PYTHONPATH = 'my director' but so far nothing has worked. Problem seems to be that python cannot find mysite folder

Comment: Make sure you have `__init__.py` within mysite.

Comment: I recommend to go step by step through the tutorial to learn the basics. In your case I guess having a project is not enough to run the server, you need to define an app and add it to the INSTLLED_APPS in settings.py.

Comment: I used django-admin startproject mysite
to create the mysite folder, there is an _init__.py file there.

Comment: Can you tell us your Django version. If you created using startproject __init__.py file will be there...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm answering my own question again.

For some strange reason, Python is unable to find the app folder /mysite and even though I set

```
PYTHONPATH = C:\...\mysite
```

It did not work

I found a hack to include the directory by inserting this after

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\\xampp\\your\\path\\site1")  <--- insert this line (3)
```

in manage.py, this forces python to look for your app folder when it runs the server. Put the double slashes as well.